Looking for new laptop with multiple external monitor capabilities
I'm looking for a new laptop (dual boot with Windows and Linux) that supports at least 2 external monitors as I do development work.
Graphics aren't super critical. I watch Netflix occasionally so a nice resolution would be an added bonus. I would assume anything purchased today will have decent graphics. It's more important that the graphics support the multiple monitors. Price range is $700 - $800 USD ish......
I see comments from people that thinkpads work with linux but no specific models. I'm not very fond of Dell. I used them at work and wasn't impressed, but I won't rule them out.
Any suggestions from someone that has 2 external monitors actually running on one of the more popular Linux versions?

The Framework 13 is a bit out of your price range, but if you equip it with multiple HDMI or Displayport ports, it can support up to 3 external displays (okay technically 4 but then the internal display doesn't work anymore, because of GPU limitations). I currently run Ubuntu 24.04 on mine, occasionally with external displays. Works quite nicely
Also FYI, most Thinkpad praizers like the T480, I have not tried it myself though
